# Page does not change after I set an option button with HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit, page-refresh

I am using HtmlUnit to navigate through the Web of knowledge web page. I am using the code below to set an option button so that results on the page would be sorted appropriately. Unfortunately, nothing happens when I execute the code. Results on the page remains sorted in the same way as they ware before.

```
HtmlSelect ssort = (HtmlSelect) pageX.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\'topNavBar\']/tbody/tr/td[3]/form/select");

HtmlOption optionA = ssort.getOptionByValue("LC.D;PY.D;AU.A;SO.A;VL.D;PG.A");

ssort.setSelectedAttribute(optionA, true);

ssort.click();
```

I debuged the code and there is no errors. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, functions like the `.click()` and `.setSelectedAttribute(HTMLOption, boolean)`(See [JavaDoc](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlSelect.html#setSelectedAttribute%28com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlOption,%20boolean%29)) will return a `HTMLPage` that in most cases is the same as the current one, however in your case it will return a different `HTMLPage`. So to capture the new page you just need to assign the return value to a `HTMLPage`.

N.B: You could also use [`getCurrentWindow()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#getCurrentWindow%28%29%20getCurrentWindow%28%29) on the `WebClient` instance.